# What is the meaning of “you bet!”?

Tags: idioms, expressions

I often hear the term "you bet!". What does it mean?

Comment: Who is saying the first sentence, and who the saying "you bet". Is person 1 saying the first sentence and person 2 is saying "you bet" , or this is a one complete sentence up to "you bet" by only one person?

Answer (score 11):

It means that some is sure of what they say, that they are (figuratively) ready to bet on it. The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has:

> **you bet:** (informal) you may be sure; certainly: *“Would you like this piece of pie?” — “You bet!”*

Answer (score 8):

Informally, it means enthusiastic agreement with a premise or question.

> Do you think you can find a home for
>   this puppy? -- You bet!